# Not an executable object: 'SELECT * FROM LoanParcel'

Tags: python, database, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I want to use the database by creating it as a dataframe, and I've used sqlalchemy for importing create_engine, but I'm stuck with the not an executable object: 'SELECT * FROM LoanParcel', where LoanParcel is the name of the database I want to create as a dataframe, how should I fix it?

views.py

```bash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://mariadb:mariadb@localhost:9051/mariadb")

def user_detail(req, id):
    conn = engine.connect()
    QLoanParcel = "SELECT * FROM LoanParcel"
    dfParcel = pd.read_sql(QLoanParcel, conn)
    conn.close()
    df = dfParcel.drop(["id", "date_add", "start_date"], axis = 1)
    return render(req,'pages/user_detail.html')
```

Comment: did you import `pymysql` library?

Comment: [Duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75464429/5320906)

Answer (score 11):

SQLAlchemy 2 introduced breaking changes, you need to wrap your SQL query in a [`text`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) to create an executable object.

Also, `LoanParcel` is a table not a database in your example.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://mariadb:mariadb@localhost:9051/mariadb")

def user_detail(req, id):
    conn = engine.connect()
    QLoanParcel = text("SELECT * FROM LoanParcel")
    dfParcel = pd.read_sql(QLoanParcel, conn)
    conn.close()
    df = dfParcel.drop(["id", "date_add", "start_date"], axis = 1)
    return render(req,'pages/user_detail.html')
```